# ios Accessibility Focus trapped on status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, voiceover

I have a scenario in my app where I am modally presenting my view with animation. When I dismiss the view the accessibility focus is not visible anywhere on the screen. When I tap insanely on the screen it gets trapped on the status bar. Even if I try tapping on views, the focus remains on the status bar elements.

Comment: @shashank Kaushik : Did u get any answer?  I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: How did you solve it? I have the same issue

Comment: Same here,did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
```

To:

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```